# Convert adjacency matrix to edge list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, graph

How can I convert an adjacency matrix as pandas `DataFrame` to an edge list? For example:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  0  0  1  1
1  1  0  1  1  0
2  1  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0
4  1  0  0  1  0
```

Desired result:

```
[(0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (4, 0), (4, 3)]
```

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
x = 5
table = []
row = []
for i in range(x):
  for j in range(x):
    if i == j :
      row.append(0)
    else :
      row.append(random.randint(0,1))
  table.append(row)
  row = []
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, replace `0` by `NA`, [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) (which drops the NA by default), and convert the index to list:

```
df.replace(0, pd.NA).stack().index.to_list()
```

output:

```
[(0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (4, 0), (4, 3)]
```

matching input:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  0  0  1  1
1  1  0  1  1  0
2  1  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0
4  1  0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `numpy` function [`argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```
np.argwhere(df.values == 1).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [4, 0], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `== 1`. e.g. `np.argwhere(df.values)` should do it.